# Looking for a script to fix multiple closing tags in xml file

Tags: xml, tags

I am looking to fix some files that I receive from another system. They should be valid  xml files but
the problem is that the structure is broken and I have one tag opening but multiple tags closing. It looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?><openTag></closeTag></closeTag></closeTag>
```

I am looking for a script to check the file and eliminate all the closing tags except the last one. This way I will get the desired result: one open -> close tag with all the information in it and a valid xml file.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: First rule is: if someone sends you broken goods, don't try to repair them, send them back and ask for a refund or replacement. Repairing broken XML is a desperation measure to be used only in emergencies when everything else has failed. You're essentially writing a parser for a new language (best to forget that it has any resemblance to XML) and your first job when writing a parser is to create a specification for the (non-XML) language that you want to parse.

Comment: @MichaelKay you are correct. At the moment I am looking for a quick fix (if possible) until other people work on fixing the issues from the system.